# Load data from web service and show in Recycler View inside a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: web-services, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I have 3 fragments inside a FragmentPagerAdapter and I want to call a web service and load data asynchronous in a Recycler View . 
Everything work correctly and data recevie successfully but Recycler View show nothing at all until I swipe Fragment at least 2 position and after back to that fragment recycler view show data.
what's problem? how can I solve it?

these are my code:

**ActivityMain.java**

```
@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragmentPagerMain);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    FragmentNavigationDrawer fragNavDrawer = (FragmentNavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.  fragment_navigation_drawer);
    fragNavDrawer.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout), toolbar);

    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()  );
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(3);
    SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pagerTabLayout); 
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FragmentList.getInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return FragmentList.getInstance(position);
        case 2:
            return FragmentList.getInstance(position);
        default:
            return FragmentList.getInstance(position);
    }
}
```

**FragmentList.java**

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

private ViewGroup view;
private ArrayList<ModelPurchase> data = new ArrayList<>();
private MyRecyclerPurchaseList adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public static Fragment getInstance(int catId) {
    FragmentList fragment = new FragmentList();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("catId", catId);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);


    new HttpRequests().new PurchasedList(new HttpRequests.RequestCompeleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompeletd(ArrayList<ModelPurchase> arrayList) {
            data = arrayList;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }).getList();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listAll);
    adapter = new MyRecyclerPurchaseList(getActivity(), data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    return view;
}}
```

Comment: somebody please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I had approximately the same issue. Setting an `adapter` to a `RecyclerView` needs to be done in `OnCreateView`. So you we need somehow to recall `OnCreateView` when our data has finished loading.

This can be done by detaching then reattaching the `fragment`, so your code will look like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    // use a boolean to prevent loading data twice...
    if ( !dataIsLoaded )
    {
    new HttpRequests().new PurchasedList(new HttpRequests.RequestCompeleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompeleted(ArrayList<ModelPurchase> arrayList) {
        data = arrayList;
        dataIsLoaded = true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Detach then attach the fragment
        FragmentTransaction = ft getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(FragmentList.this);
        ft.attach(FragmentList.this);
        ft.commit();
    }
    }).getList();
    }

    else
    {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listAll);
        adapter = new MyRecyclerPurchaseList(getActivity(), data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        return view;
     }
```

}}